# adding a string to another string turning to a double or char then calculating result

Tags: java

basically,i want to make a simple calculator

I want to take a string input from the keyboard, so if its a number or '.' it will add it to the String and if it is a char(+-*/) it will do the calculation.

So you first enter a 3

then a 4, which will make the string 34, it then converts it to a double then do a + then enter 3 then . then 34 so the string is 3.34 then you press = and it gives the answer.
I have read in the value
then

```
string newstring = value;
if (value.equals("0") |value.equals("1") etc
in = in + newstring;
}
```

then

```
try 
{
setOperand(convert in to double)
if (flag == 1)
{
operand1 = convert in to double
result = operand1
flag = 0;
}// only does it for the first operand

getresult() which is if + then result + getOperand
catch
try 
changes to char
```

for some reason when i just do 3= the result = 0, or 3 then . then 2 etc

Comment: Can you post the code and format it?  Kind of hard to tell what is going on as is.

Comment: Wow...please read the question you just posted and decide whether that reflects the effort you wanted to put into helping us help you.  If you choose to edit it to bring it to a quality worth answering, you can use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5475829/edit) below the question.

Comment: You are asking the same question over and over again - don't you think it is time to read and try to understand the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Can I make a suggestion? Get the entire String to calculate in one line, and then parse that line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AshanCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my calculator. Please enter a math equation:");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String equation = in.nextLine(); // get the ENTIRE line from the keyboard
                                         // not just one character at a time

        double result = evaluateEquation(equation);

    }

    private static double evaluateEquation(String equation) {
        /**
         * your mission - fill this in
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use the method isDigit() of Char instead of using if(value.equals("0)||value.equals("1") etc .